# Django, annotate + values duplicates records

Tags: python, django, orm, django-orm

I have a model called Location and I'm querying the model with filters that yield 4000 objects:

```py
count = Location.objects.filter(**filters).count()

4000
```

there is a related Model called KPIs, each Location has many KPIs and there are 2,944,000 KPIs records.

I have a very complex query for the Location that annotates a lot of the KPIs data.

the annotations:

```py
def contribute_annotations(self):
    user = self.request.user
    self.kpis = user.user_selected_kpis.get_all_kpis_qs()
    kpis_names = tuple(kpi.internal_name for kpi in self.kpis)
    branch_date = Subquery(BranchKPIs.objects.
                           filter(branch__location__id=OuterRef(ID)).
                           order_by('-date').
                           values(DATE)[:1]
                           )
    # summing the members amount
    filters_for_branch = (
            Q(location_branches__prem=True) &
            ~Q(location_branches__branch_scores__members_count=0) &
            Q(location_branches__branch_scores__date=F(BRANCH_DATE))
    )
    sum_of_members_prem_count = Coalesce(Sum('location_branches__branch_scores__members_count',
                                             output_field=IntegerField(),
                                             filter=filters_for_branch),
                                         0)

    # location kpis prefetch object
    location_kpis_qs = LocationKPIs.objects.filter(date__range=month_range).only(DATE, LOCATION, *kpis_names)
    prefetch_location_kpis = Prefetch(lookup=RelatedNames.LOCATION_SCORES,
                                      queryset=location_kpis_qs,
                                      )

    assigned_members_count_of_latest = Case(When(location_scores__date=F(LATEST_DATE),
                                                 then=f'location_scores__assigned_members_count'))
    members_count_of_latest = Case(When(location_scores__date=F(LATEST_DATE),
                                        then=f'location_scores__members_count'))

    # kpis annotations for Avg, Trends, and Sizing
    kpis_annotations, alias_for_trends, kpis_objects = {}, {}, {}

    for kpi in self.kpis:
        name = kpi.internal_name
        # annotating the last kpi score
        kpis_annotations[name] = Case(When(location_scores__date=F('latest_date'),
                                           then=f'location_scores__{name}'), default=0)

        # annotating the kpi's month avg
        alias_for_trends[f'{name}_avg'] = Coalesce(
            Avg(f'location_scores__{name}',
                filter=Q(location_scores__date__range=month_range), output_field=IntegerField()
                ),
            0
        )
        # comparing latest score to the monthly avg in order to determine the kpi's trend
        when_equal = When(**{f'{name}_avg': F(name)}, then=0)
        when_trend_is_down = When(**{f'{name}_avg__gt': F(name)}, then=-1)
        when_trend_is_up = When(**{f'{name}_avg__lt': F(name)}, then=1)
        kpi_trend = Case(when_equal, when_trend_is_up, when_trend_is_down,
                         default=0, output_field=IntegerField())

        # annotating the score color
        when_red = When(**{f'{name}__gte': kpi.location_level_red_threshold.lower,
                           f'{name}__lte': kpi.location_level_red_threshold.upper},
                        then=1
                        )
        when_yellow = When(**{f'{name}__gte': kpi.location_level_yellow_threshold.lower,
                              f'{name}__lte': kpi.location_level_yellow_threshold.upper},
                           then=2
                           )
        when_green = When(**{f'{name}__gte': kpi.location_level_green_threshold.lower,
                             f'{name}__lte': kpi.location_level_green_threshold.upper},
                          then=3
                          )
        score_type = Case(when_red, when_yellow, when_green, default=2)

        # outputs kpi : {score: int, trend: int, score_type: int}
        kpis_objects[name] = JSONObject(
            score=F(name),
            trend=kpi_trend,
            score_type=score_type
        )
    # cases for the pin size of the location, it depends on how many members are in it
    when_in_s_size = When(
        Q(member_count__gte=settings.S_LOCATION_SIZE[0]) & Q(member_count__lte=settings.S_LOCATION_SIZE[-1]),
        then=1)
    when_in_m_size = When(
        Q(member_count__gte=settings.M_LOCATION_SIZE[0]) & Q(member_count__lte=settings.M_LOCATION_SIZE[-1]),
        then=2)
    when_in_l_size = When(
        Q(member_count__gte=settings.L_LOCATION_SIZE[0]) & Q(member_count__lte=settings.L_LOCATION_SIZE[-1]),
        then=3)
    when_in_xl_size = When(
        Q(member_count__gte=settings.XL_LOCATION_SIZE[0]) & Q(member_count__lte=settings.XL_LOCATION_SIZE[-1]),
        then=4)
    location_size = Case(when_in_s_size, when_in_m_size, when_in_l_size, when_in_xl_size,
                         default=2,
                         output_field=IntegerField())

    # location's address string
    location_str = Concat(LOCATION__STREET, LOCATION__CITY, LOCATION__COUNTRY,
                          output_field=CharField())

    return (
    sum_of_members_prem_count, prefetch_location_kpis, assigned_members_count_of_latest, members_count_of_latest,
    kpis_annotations, location_size, alias_for_trends, location_str, kpis_names, kpis_objects, branch_date)
```

```py
filters = {'user': self.request.user, ACTIVE: True}
(sum_of_members_prem_count, prefetch_location_kpis, assigned_members_count_of_latest, members_count_of_latest,
    kpis_annotations, location_size, alias_for_trends, location_str, kpis_names, kpis_objects, branch_date) = self.contribute_annotations()

query_set = (Location.objects.
             filter(**filters).
             select_related(RelatedNames.LOCATION).
             prefetch_related(prefetch_location_kpis).
             alias(latest_date=Max('scores__date'),
                   branch_date=branch_date,
                   **alias_for_trends,
                   **kpis_annotations
                   ).
             annotate(members_prem_count=sum_of_members_prem,
                      members_count=members_count_of_latest,
                      assigned_members_count=assigned_count_of_latest,
                      farm_latitude=Min(LOCATION__LATITUDE),
                      farm_longitude=Min(LOCATION__LONGITUDE),
                      address=location_str,
                      farm_size=farm_size,
                      latest_date=Max('farm_scores__date'),
                      **kpis_objects
                      ).
             values(ID, NAME, ADMIN_EMAIL, ADMIN_PHONE, MEMBERS_PREM_COUNT,
                    MEMBERS_COUNT, ASSIGNED_MEMBERS_COUNT, SIZE, ADDRESS,
                    latitude=F(LOCATION_LATITUDE), longitude=F(LOCATION_LONGITUDE), *kpis_names
                    )
             )
```

this query yields 2,944,000 records, which means each for each KPI record and not Location.
I tried adding distinct calls in several ways but I either end up with:

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

Or the query just ignores it and doesn't add distinct location objects.

the docs suggest that values and distinct don't play nice together and that probably somewhere there is an order by that breaks it.
I've looked at all the involved models, queries and subqueries and removed the order by but it still doesn't work.

I also tried adding this to the query:

```py
query_set.query.clear_ordering(True)
query_set = query_set.order_by(ID).distinct(ID)
```

but this raises that NotImplementedError

Comment: As it is your code cannot be understood, you have too many variables appearing out of nowhere. Please see how to write a [mre].

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I wanted to avoid adding all of those origins as it very long, but will edit

Comment: Do note that other than _reproducible_ it **also** needs to be _minimal_...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure why it's like this and maybe in some cases it won't work.
But, I changed the query to the following:

```py
query_set = (Location.objects.
             filter(**filters).
             select_related(RelatedNames.LOCATION).
             prefetch_related(prefetch_location_kpis).
             alias(latest_date=Max('scores__date'),
                   branch_date=branch_date,
                   **alias_for_trends,
                   **kpis_annotations
                   ).
             distinct(ID).
             annotate(members_prem_count=sum_of_members_prem,
                      members_count=members_count_of_latest,
                      assigned_members_count=assigned_count_of_latest,
                      farm_latitude=Min(LOCATION__LATITUDE),
                      farm_longitude=Min(LOCATION__LONGITUDE),
                      address=location_str,
                      farm_size=farm_size,
                      latest_date=Max('farm_scores__date'),
                      **kpis_objects
                      ).
             distinct(ID)
             )
```

and overriding Django's source code in django/db/models/sql/compiler.py
line 595

```py
     if grouping:
                    if distinct_fields:
                        raise NotImplementedError('annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.')
                    order_by = order_by or self.connection.ops.force_no_ordering()
                    result.append('GROUP BY %s' % ', '.join(grouping))
                    if self._meta_ordering:
                        order_by = None
                if having:
                    result.append('HAVING %s' % having)
                    params.extend(h_params)
```

just commented out the if distinct_fields condition

```py
    if grouping:
                    # if distinct_fields:
                    #     raise NotImplementedError('annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.')
                    order_by = order_by or self.connection.ops.force_no_ordering()
                    result.append('GROUP BY %s' % ', '.join(grouping))
                    if self._meta_ordering:
                        order_by = None
                if having:
                    result.append('HAVING %s' % having)
                    params.extend(h_params)
```